# smart contracts and ICO: how to begin with when low speed connexion, old computer, low code understanding?

Tags: contract-development

Question: having read https://www.ethereum.org/ and documentation regarding a) designing a token and b) kickstart a project, **I wander what is the best way for a beginner like me to run a project crownsale**, assuming 1) my PC connection in remote place is really quiet low, 2) my PC is old without any high speed graphic card, 3) my code understanding level and my hability to code is limited (I'm not coder, but I code arduino, web site, LaTex, etc ...) ?

Do my self , Or use a pre-existant smart-contract on-line service?

Sorry for this very beginner question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike running a full Ethereum node, contract development does not require heavy computation or a fast internet connection.

You can do contract development directly in your web browser using something like Remix: https://remix.ethereum.org/.

There are also online tutorials teaching you the basics of contract development which just require your browser: https://cryptozombies.io/

You can do more advance local contract development using the truffle suite, which supports a simulated blockchain (Ganache) for end to end testing: https://truffleframework.com/

Finally, once you want to deploy your contract, these services allow you to do that without needing to set up a node on your machine.

Comment: Thank you @Shawn-tabrizi for such information. I did not know about  [remix.ethereum.org](https://remix.ethereum.org), which seems part of ethereum project as explained in [ethereum wiki](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Remix). Thank you also for other links you mentioned.

Comment: If you feel this post fully answers your question, feel free to mark it as resolved so that others searching for similar problems can more easily find it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on your needs. If you want to learn how to do it and want to continue doing it in the future, then you should do it all yourself. But if instead you just want to get it done once and then forget it, you can use some online service.

Your PC connection speed will not be an issue really as you can use a centralized service such as Infura to connect to the blockchain, so you don't need to run your own node. Also your PC's configuration doesn't matter much if you use an external node.

If you want to run your own node instead of using an external service, you will need to have decent specifications for your computer.

Comment: Do you mean there are online services which offer way to "write" a smart-contract, giving access to "control" to it, and which also place it on the blockchain across their own node connexion? Do they propose standard smart-contract "templates"? Or only a door to blockchain for a smart-contract code that have to be fully developed by my own way before ?

Comment: You can either use services such as Infura which only offer access to the blockchain (a node connection) or use whatever services which either write a contract for you or offer a fully-automated service to create a token and a crowdsale for it. Or something in-between. Of course you have to pay for some of these services, but Infura is currently free to use.